# How to make a rain with particle system and achieve a impact effect with rigidbody on bushes

Tags: particles, rigid-body-simulation

I hava a ground which contains a particle system(bushes) and i want to achieve my bushes transformed when the rain drops hit the plants.

This is my scene
[image]

Comment: I would suggest having a few select real raindrop that effect the bush, this way you wouldn't take days to form the physics calculation.

Comment: Thats a decent and proper idea,no doubt i will use that technic